# How to select the first item in list by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i want to select the first item in a list by default.So when i open the view i want the item **Plafond sécurité sociale** under **Général** to be selected by default.

```js
$("#général").val($("#général a:first").selectedIndex());
```

```html
  
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <a class="mdc-list-item" style="width:100%;margin-right:3px;margin-left:3px;">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="row" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#général" style="cursor:pointer">
              <span class="user" style="font-weight:bold">Général</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="col-md-1 chevron-down" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#général" style="float:right;margin-right:0px">
              <i class="général_arrow material-icons float-right material-expand ripple" style="color: #0047FD !important;">
                         expand_more
                         </i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="général" class="collapse">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="PSS" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer;">
                   Plafond sécurité sociale
                   </a>
          <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="SMIC" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer;">
                   Smic
                   </a>
          <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="CSG" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer;">
                   CSG CRDS
                   </a>
          <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="AGM" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" style="cursor:pointer">
                   Abattement gérant majoritaire
                   </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i add modify my function to have a good result.

Comment: `#general` is a div, it doesn't have a `.val()` and `a` is an anchor, it doesn't have a `selectedIndex`.  Given that your "list" is a custom list, you'll need to determine / provide the class that's added when selected, then it would be `$("#général a:first").addClass("selected")`

Comment: `$( "a.mdc-list-item:first" ).click();`

Comment: @ShivKumarBaghel I did it but the page always redirect to the home page so i can't see my view

Comment: use `event.preventDefault`  like . `$( "a.mdc-list-item:first" ).click( function(event){ event.preventDefault(); } ); `

Comment: @ShivKumarBaghel  Now i can see my view but the first item is not selected it seems that the item has been selected but quickly it return not selected

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are asking for, but the select the item you want and add styling of your choice.

```
$('.mdc-list-item')[0]
$('.mdc-list-item:first-child()')[0]
$('.mdc-list-item:first')[0]
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hUK4h5qE  You are applying the class else where, this example does work.

Comment: I did it like in the link but i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#item1").addClass("selected");

  $(".list-item").click(function() {
    $(".list-item").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  max-width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
a,
a:hover {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
a.selected {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="item1" href="#" class="list-item">Item 1</a>
<a id="item2" href="#" class="list-item">Item 2</a>
<a id="item3" href="#" class="list-item">Item 3</a>
```